# How to open files in a separate tabs

Tags: adobe-brackets

I want to keep all my working files in a separate tabs in Brackets since, I am finding bit difficult to open the file in the LHS panel under "Working Files". Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Tabs for Brackets extension](https://github.com/albertxing/brackets-tabs) will show traditional tabs along the top, although only when the sidebar is hidden. (Though it would probably be easy to hack that extension to do it all the time instead).

But bear in mind that the "working files" section is really the same thing as tabs, just rendered in a vertical stack on the side to conserve screen real estate.  You can open, close, and drag to reorder the items just like tabs.  If clicking them is a pain, you can use Ctrl+Tab to navigate in MRU order, or use my [File Navigation Shortcuts extension](https://github.com/peterflynn/brackets-editor-nav/blob/master/package.json) for hotkeys to navigate in linear list order (or use Quick Open to jump to any file based on a fragment of its name).

Comment: As an update to this answer; The Tabs for Brackets extension that was linked to didn't work for me, so I installed the Documents Toolbar (https://github.com/dnbard/brackets-documents-toolbar), which works perfect for me.

Comment: Funny, I think of tabs as the same thing as the sidebar except a horizontal list to save screen real estate. :)

Comment: I‘d like to know if there is a way, at this time 2022, an option to see at least 3 content tabs (a kind of 3 windows) at the Same Time, so I can see globally an HTML, a CSS and a Javascript file, and alternate it with pure php pages. 

The CSS is very narrow for nature and will no take too much width. I work with two monitors, so in the second monitor I can just see the render page from the browser.  Something like codepen where you can easily see 4 windows at the same time: html, css, js and the rendered by the browser. Is it possible with brackets? any plug in for this?

Answer (score 7):

Tabs for Brackets extension from selected answer isn't support latest Brackets API changes (from Sprint 44 release). Documents Toolbar ([github.com/dnbard/brackets-documents-toolbar](http://github.com/dnbard/brackets-documents-toolbar)) from kramer65 comment use that API and support split-view (new feature from Sprint 44 release).

**The official page for the extension Documents Toolbar** with the downloadable ZIP files is http://brackets.dnbard.com/extension/dnbard.documents-toolbar

Answer (score 5):

I was also searching for it. Finally found [this plugin](https://github.com/demonmhon/brackets-working-file-tabs) to be helpful.

**How to install**

1. Open Brackets, Go to File -> Extension manager...
2. You can find "Install from URL..." link at the bottom-left of the popup
3. Click on that and provide the GitHub URL https://github.com/demonmhon/brackets-working-file-tabs
4. Once installed, close the popup and go to View -> Show working file as tabs...

Here is how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but i was able to solve it later. On your menu bar, click on "View" and scroll right down to the last one, you will see "show tabs", simply click on it and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom Work](https://github.com/alessandrio/custom-work-for-brackets) behaves pretty well for me. It appears to be deprecated, but still available in Extension Manager.